# No implicit Ordering defined for T with Int (Scala)

Tags: generics, scala, scala-collections, implicit

A class of mine is a generic and defines `iv` as `MHashMap[DateTime, T]`. `MHashMap` is an alias for `scala.collection.mutableHashMap`. Then I use this code to expose a minimum finding functionality

```
def minimum: BigDecimal = {
  iv match {
    case dtMcM: MHashMap[DateTime, MyCustomClass] => dtMcM.minBy(_._2.bdField)._2.bdField
    case dtBdM: MHashMap[DateTime, BigDecimal] => dtBdM.minBy(_._2)._2
    case dtDlM: MHashMap[DateTime, Double] => dtDlM.minBy(_._2)._2.toBigDecimal
    case dtItM: MHashMap[DateTime, Int] => dtItM.minBy(_._2)._2
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported underlying type")
  }
}
```

But the complier complains:

```
No implicit Ordering defined for T with Int.
case dtItM: MHashMap[DateTime, Int] => dtItM.minBy(_._2)._2
```

And the same for `Double` and `BigDecimal` cases.

How is that the compiler can not even recognize `Int` to apply default ordering? Curious thing is that it desn't seem to have any problem with a BigDecimal field of my own custom class.

Comment: I'm not sure what is causing the error, but the code above will unfortunately not work due to type erasure. It is not possible to `match` on a type parameter, only on the type constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `Int <: T with Int`. Now, if you are going to use `Ordering[Int]` for it, then you need `Ordering[T with Int] <: Ordering[Int]`, which means `Ordering` must be contravariant. Unfortunately, `Ordering` is not contravariant (even though it could -- and it is in Scalaz).

Comment: Are you sure? I don't really understand and see no way to check but would like to accept the answer if you are sure this is what causes the problem. Practically I have solved the problem for myself, but an irrelevant way.

Comment: @Ivan I'm just explaining why `Ordering[Int]` can't be used for `Ordering[T with Int]`. What Owen said -- that you can't match on type parameters -- is correct, so this approach is doomed to begin with. Also, I have no idea why `T` is showing up -- but you didn't ask about that. :-)